# Schedule unittest python files with crontab; how to give 5-sec pause between each unittest?

Tags: python, selenium, cron, python-unittest

I am scheduling some unittest python files using crontab.

crontab -e:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * cd /Users/HeyJude/ntry_selenium && /Users/HeyJude/ntry_selenium/ladderPattern.sh.command
```

ladderPattern.sh.command:
    #!/bin/sh

```
sleep 10
python /Users/HeyJude/ntry_selenium/result.py  &
sleep 1
python /Users/HeyJude/ntry_selenium/predict.py &
sleep 1
python /Users/HeyJude/ntry_selenium/lds24.py &
```

those 3 files (result.py, predict.py, lds24.py) are all python unittest files. they are all something like:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        # ... lines of code
    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        # ... lines of code
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        # ... lines of code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I want to run predict.py after result.py is completely done, but maybe because those 3 files are unittest file, all 3 starts almost at the same time!
Maybe terminal assumes that each file are done, when test method inside unittesting class starts! But I am not sure why this happens.

my question is, I want to make sure next one starts only when previous one ends. and I also want to put 5-sec amount of pause between python files.

Is there any way to to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `&` from the end of your commandlines.  This is what is causing the script to continue to the next command immediately, instead of waiting for the current command to finish.
2. Change `sleep 1` to `sleep 5` if you desire a 5-sec sleep between commands.
3. That should be it!